# Ruby Array that counts to a given value

Tags: arrays, ruby, count

Trying to do something like:

```
def action(number)

nums = [1...number]
code_here...

end
```

Do I need to write up a "count" snippet for this to work? Or is something similar to what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: _"that counts to a given value"_ sounds more like a loop or maybe a method that _yields_ those values.

Comment: @Stefan It does, and I'd be able to do it in a loop, but I'm just trying to declare a variable whose value is the number and all the numbers before it starting at 1. Felt declaring it as an array off rip, as opposed to looping for those values and then pushing them into an array, would result in a faster log time. It's for leetcode and I like seeing "100%" on speed, though sometimes that means coming up with "hacky" solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions for this as following:

**If you want to add number in the array than:**

```
nums = [*1..number]
# or
nums = (1..number).to_a
```

**Ignoring last number than:**

```
nums = [*1...number]
# or
nums = (1...number).to_a
```

Comment: It actually kinda hurts to be this close yet completely miss the target.

Comment: Well maybe a few more than 2 options `1.upto(number)` or  `Array.new(number) {|i| i + 1}` or to start at 0 `number.times` or  `Array.new(number).each_index`  etc.

Answer (score 4):

There's another option to use enumerators:

```
1.upto(10).to_a #=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

There are quite a few useful ones. For example, if you only need every other number up to certain number you can use:

```
0.step(100, 2).to_a #=> [0,2,4,6,8,..., 98,100]
```

Another option would be to use Array constructor:

```
Array.new(10) { |i| i + 1 } #=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

which is a bit more verbose, but gives you much more freedom:

```
Array.new(10) { |i| 2 ** i } #=> [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,256,512]
```

Comment: Hey, bro, long time no see. Still banging away on that piano, eh? How about something to represent the weird category, like `(1...).first(10)`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland weird it is `Enumerator.produce(1,&:succ)` (less than 2.7 `Enumerator.new {|y| i = 0; loop {y << i+=1}}`)

Comment: @engineersmnky, maybe add `.first(10)`.

Comment: `1.step.take(10)` is another option